# Multiple master pages in a single application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

Is it a good design to have multiple masterpages in an application.
I am building a website using Asp.net MVC with different type of users like, admin, employee, general user, etc

And every user once logged in have different type of controls on the website, so I was planning to use different master page for each user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a good design, and make sure to layer them appropriately. Master pages specific to controllers should be placed them in the appropriate view folder.

Answer (score 1):

If it makes life easier for you and your users, than I see no reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how about Asp.net MVC, but in Asp.net master pages inheritance is possible. You may create `site.master`, and `admin.master`, `employee.master`, etc that all inherit from site.master.

But take care of master pages inheritance. In my project, it seems that sometimes paths may point to wrong locations. I don't know whether it is my mistake or is a bug.